# A recursive error occurs when defining the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class student(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    @name.setter
    def name(self,name:str):
        self.name = name
    @property
    def score(self):
        return self.score
    @score.setter
    def score(self,score:int):
        self.score = score
if __name__ == "__main__":
    chen = student()
    chen.score = 625
    chen.name = "chen"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Project\PyProject\Learn-Python3\main.py", line 242, in <module>
    chen.score = 625
  File "d:\Project\PyProject\Learn-Python3\main.py", line 238, in score
    self.score = score
  File "d:\Project\PyProject\Learn-Python3\main.py", line 238, in score
    self.score = score
  File "d:\Project\PyProject\Learn-Python3\main.py", line 238, in score
    self.score = score
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I used two decorators so that I could call the method as a property but a problem occurred.

In front is my code,at the back is the error.

Does this have anything to do with recursion?

After all it's just a class problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think logically about the code. Where it says `return self.score`, *where is that value supposed to come from?* Names can only mean one thing at a time. If `score` is the property, it cannot also simultaneously be an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different attribute name (typically `self._score`) inside the property methods:

```
...
    @property
    def score(self):
        return self._score
    @score.setter
    def score(self,score:int):
        self._score = score
...
```

Otherwise `self.score = score` calls the setter `def score(self, score)`, which sets `self.score = score`, which calls the setter `def score(self, score)` again, etc., hence the `RecursionError`.